# Using custom AccessDecisionManager with HttpSecurity addFilterBefore does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

The custom AccessDecisionManager does not get invoked either when filter is added or otherwise. Ideally would like to set filterBefore and custom AccessDecisionManager (using SpringBoot 1.5.2-release version). Alternately would like to call setRolePrefix on default RoleVoter. Also added DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor as mentioned in Section 8.3 of Spring 3 to 4 migration guide, but still RoleVoter looks for "ROLE_" prefix

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters 
          = Arrays.asList(
            new WebExpressionVoter(),
            new RoleVoter(),
            new AuthenticatedVoter());
        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
        .anyRequest().authenticated(); 

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're expecting your `AccessDecisionManager` to get called to grant/deny access to your secure methods.

Try the following:

1. Remove the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation from your `SecurityConfig`.
2. Move the annotation to another configuration class that extends `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`.

For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return this.accessDecisionManager;
    }

}
```

**Explanation:**

`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` takes care of creating the method interceptors, and it doesn't look for an `AccessDecisionManager` bean to use. It must be provided one via an overridden method.

**NOTE:**
By default, **two** `AccessDecisionManagers` are used: one for filters (created by `AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer`) and another to secure methods (created by `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`).

> Alternately would like to call setRolePrefix on default RoleVoter

You could do this without ever touching the default `AccessDecisionManager`s:

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
}
```

This will set the role prefix to `""` on **both** default `AccessDecisionManagers`.